# Extend Time Capsule Wi-fi network

Tags: wifi, time-capsule

I have a time capsule that I use as my Wi-fi router instead of my isp’s device. The Wi-fi reaches most of the house, except the area near the front door and my ring door bell.

I have a tp-link powerline Wi-fi adapter that I used to proved Wi-fi in an out building. It mimicked the sad and password of the time capsules. Worked fine out there. Moved it into the main house to improve my network, but it devices close to it seemed to grind to a halt. I presumed it was because the time capsule was 5ghz and and the tp-link was 2.5ghz.

Is this normal? I thought it would work as my time capsule has 2.5 & 5ghz Wi-fi.

Hope that makes sense! Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here.  However, a 2.5GHz radio *cannot* connect to a 5GHz radio.  It's like trying to listen to a radio station set at 97.3 MHz when your radio is tuned to 100.7 MHz.  Your TC can handle both, while the TP can only handle one, so it's only broadcasting the 2.4GHz signal.

Comment: Sorry, it isn’t clear. My time capsule has 2.4ghz and 5ghz using the same name and password etc. Can I use the tp-link which just has 2.4ghz using the same name password etc?